# How can monads determine ordering if their information is lost upon normalization?

Tags: haskell, monads

If I understood correctly, a `monad` is just the implementation of a bind `>>=` and a `return` operator following certain rules which basically compose 2 functions of different return types together. So, for example, those are equivalent:

```
putStrLn "What is your name?"
>>= (\_ -> getLine)
>>= (\name -> putStrLn ("Welcome, " ++ name ++ "!"))

(bind (putStrLn "What is your name?")
      (bind
          (\_ -> getLine)
          (\name -> putStrLn ("Welcome, " ++ name ++ "!"))))
```

But if we strongly normalize this expression, the final result will be just:

```
(putStrLn ("Welcome, " ++ getline ++ "!"))
```

The first statement `(putStrLn "What is your name?")` is completely lost. Also, getLine looks like a function with no arguments, which is nonsense. So how does this work, and what is the *actual* definition of the `>>=` and `return` functions?

Comment: >>= for IO just builds up a description of a program that can do I/O. Your "normalization" process seems very invalid

Comment: "But if we strongly normalize this expression, the final result will be" Care to write down the reductions? "function with no arguments, which is nonsense" Says who?

Comment: @n.m. I can't write the reductions without the proper definition of `>>=` which I couldn't find. It is of my intuition that `putStrLn "What is your name?"` is lost because the following function doesn't use its argument (`\_ -> getline`). Please sorry if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @n.m. AFAIK Haskell functions have a fixed arity of 1 so you can't create a function without arguments.

Comment: I've always found this page to be a great explanation of how the IO monad enforces order: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IO_inside

Comment: "It is of my intuition that putStrLn "What is your name?" is lost" Your intuition is wrong. The result of `putStrLn` does *not* go to the discarded argument of `(\_ -> getLine)`. To see why, look at `readLine >>= putStrLn`. Do you think the result of `readLine` goes to the argument of `putStrLn`? Nope, the types do not match. One is `String` and the other is `IO String`.

Comment: "Haskell functions have a fixed arity of 1" It's a terminology question. You can use this terminology, or some other. Either way `getLine` has no arguments and it is *not* nonsense. `5` has no arguments, is it nonsense?

Comment: @n.m. `5` has no arguments? Never got a ``No instance for (Num (a0 -> t0)) arising from the literal `5'`` error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your logical misstep is that you assume certain reduction rules hold which do not. In particular, you appear to be using

```
f >>= (\x -> g x)  ====  g f
```

If that held then, yes, monads would be pretty silly: `(>>=)` would just be `flip ($)`. But it doesn't, in general, hold at all. In fact, the very reason it doesn't hold is what provides monads an opportunity to be interesting.

---

For a little bit of further exploration, here's the one monad where `(>>=) == flip ($)` (basically) holds.

```
newtype Identity a = Identity { unIdentity :: a }
```

To make our equations work out, we'll have to use that `Identity a ~ a`. This isn't strictly true, obviously, but let's pretend. In particular, `Identity . unIdentity` and `unIdentity . Identity` are both identities, no-ops, and we can freely apply `Identity` or `unIdentity` however we like to make types match

```
instance Functor Identity where
  fmap f (Identity a) = Identity (f a)

instance Monad Identity where
  return a = Identity a          -- this is a no-op
  ida >>= f = f (unIdentity ida)
```

Now, in particular, we want to examine

```
ida :: Identity a
f   :: a -> b

ida >>= Identity . f          :: Identity b
===
Identity (f (unIdentity ida)) :: Identity b
```

and if we throw away the `Identity`/`unIdentity` noise and thus produce the knowledge that `ida = Identity a` for some a

```
Identity (f (unIdentity ida)) :: Identity b
===
Identity (f a)                :: Identity b
===                              ~
f a                           ::          b
```

---

So, while `(>>=) == flip ($)` forms a certain basis of intuition about `(>>=)`... in any circumstance more interesting than the `Identity` monad (and all other monads are) it doesn't hold exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a misunderstanding of how evaluation in IO proceeds in Haskell. If you look at the type signature for `(>>=)`:

```
λ: :t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

It takes a monadic value parameterized by a type `a`, and a function which accepts a type of the same type and applies it inside the function body yielding a monadic value of type `b`.

The IO monad itself is a rather degenerate monad since it has special status in Haskell's implementation. A type of `IO a` stands for a potentially impure computation which, when performed, **does some IO before returning a value of type `a`**.

> The first statement (putStrLn "What is your name?") is completely
>   lost.

The misunderstanding about this statement is that the value of `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` *does* in fact lose it's value in some sense, or more precisely it just yields the unit type  `()` to the bound function after performing the IO action of printing a string to the outside world.

> But if we strongly normalize this expression, the final result will be
>
> just: (putStrLn ("Welcome, " ++ getline ++ "!"))

It's best to think of `getLine :: IO String` as being a computation yielding a value instead of a value itself. In this case as well the function `getLine` is not *itself* substituted in but the result of the computation it performs is, which behaves like you expect it to: getting a value from stdin and printing it back out.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] what are the *actual* definitions for the `(>>=)` and `return` functions?

From section 6.1.7 (page 75) of the [Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf):

> The `IO` type serves as a tag for operations (actions) that interact with the outside world. The `IO` type is abstract: no constructors are visible to the user. `IO` is an instance of the `Monad` and `Functor` classes.

the crucial point being:

> The `IO` type is *abstract*: no constructors are visible to the user.

There are no actual (written in idiomatic Haskell) definitions - it's the implementors' choice as to which model to use: [state-threading](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.144.2237&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [continuations](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/%7Educhier/python/continuations.html), [direct effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6706442/13679816), etc. (This wasn't always the case - I provide more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557499/13679816) :-) We also benefit, as we're able to choose the most convenient model for the investigation being made.

> So how does this work [...]?

I will choose the *direct-effect* model, based on examples from Philip Wadler's [How to Declare an Imperative](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.3579&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

```
(* page 26, modified *)

type 'a io   = oi -> 'a

infix >>=
val >>=      : 'a io * ('a -> 'b io) -> 'b io
fun m >>= k  = fn Oblige => let
                              val x =   m Oblige
                              val y = k x Oblige
                            in
                              y
                            end

val return   : 'a -> 'a io
fun return x = fn Oblige => x

val putc     : char -> unit io
fun putc c   = fn Oblige => putcML c

val getc     : char io
val getc     = fn Oblige => getcML ()
```

I'm using a new type:

```
datatype oi  = Oblige
```

to reserve the `unit` type and its value `()` for the usual purpose of vacuous
results, for clarity.

(Yes - that's [Standard ML](https://www.smlnj.org/sml.html): just imagine it's 1997, and you're writing a
prototype Haskell implementation ;-)

With the help of some extra definitions:

```
val gets     : (char list) io
val putsl    : char list -> unit io
```

that Haskell code sample, modified slightly:

```
putStrLn "What is your name?"     >>= 
(\_ -> getLine                    >>=
(\name -> putStrLn (greet name)))

greet      :: String -> String
greet name =  "Welcome, " ++ name ++ "!"
```

translates to:

```
putsl "What is your name?"
>>= (fn _    => gets
>>= (fn name => putsl (greet name))
```

where:

```
val greet      : char list -> char list
fun greet name = List.concat (String.explode "Welcome, "::name::[#"!"])
```

**All going well**, the sample should simplify down to:

```
fun Oblige => let
                val x    = putsl "What is your name?" Oblige
                val name = gets Oblige
                val y    = putsl (greet name) Oblige
              in
                y
              end
```

Even though `x` isn't used it's still evaluated in Standard ML, which causes the prompt `"What is your name?"` to be displayed.

Now for a guess at the next question...*Standard ML and Haskell are both functional languages - could all that `oi` stuff be transferred across to Haskell?*

I was wrong? Meh; I'll answer it anyway - **sort of**; you can read about what I devised over [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partibles_for_composing_monads). If that was just too abominable to contemplate...well, here are those extra Standard ML definitions:

```
(* from pages 25-26, verbatim *)

val putcML    : char -> unit
fun putcML c  = TextIO.output1(TextIO.stdOut,c);

val getcML    : unit -> char
fun getcML () = valOf(TextIO.input1(TextIO.stdIn));


(* Caution: work of SML novice... *)

val gets     = fn Oblige => let
                              val c = getc Oblige
                            in
                              if c = #"\n" then
                                []
                              else
                                let
                                  val cs = gets Oblige
                                in
                                  (c::cs)
                                end
                            end

fun putsl cs = fn Oblige => let
                              val _ = putsl cs Oblige
                              val _ = putc #"\n" Oblige
                            in
                              ()
                            end

val puts     : char list -> unit io
fun puts cs  = fn Oblige => case cs of
                              []      => ()
                            | (c::cs) => let val _ = putc c Oblige in
                                         puts cs Oblige
```

Comment: You're a few years too late to this party. The OP is now quite an experienced functional programmer and is working on proof language design.

Comment: @dfeuer but current and future readers of this entry might not yet be so. (and the party continues for anyone with a bookmark on the "active [tag:haskell] posts" ... which evidently are not that many people)  :)

Answer (score 1):

It has been so long til I asked that question! The simple answer is that, no, the term I posted does **not** reduce to `putStrLn ("Welcome, " ++ getline ++ "!")`. Instead, its normal form will have the shape `bind foo (\ _ -> bind bar (\ _ -> ...))`, i.e., a chain of lambdas, which holds the ordering information I was worried about.

Comment: actually,
`putStrLn "What is your name?" >>= (\_ -> getLine) >>= (\name -> putStrLn ("Welcome, " ++ name ++ "!"))` reduces as `(bind (bind foo (\_ -> getLine)) (\name -> ...))` because `infixl 1 >>=`.