# How do you implement Haskell's IO type in Java?

Tags: java, haskell

This is my first attempt:

```
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class IO<A> {
    private Function<World,Tuple<World,A>> transform;
    private class World {
        private ArrayList<String> stdin;
        private ArrayList<String> stdout;
        public World() {
            this.stdin  = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.stdout = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }
    private class Tuple<F,S> {
        public F fst;
        public S snd;
        public Tuple(F fst, S snd) {
            this.fst = fst;
            this.snd = snd;
        }
    }
    public IO(Function<World,Tuple<World,A>> transform) {
        this.transform = transform;
    }
    public IO<A> pure(A a) {
        return new IO<A>(r -> new Tuple<World,A>(r,a));
    }
    public <B> IO<B> bind(IO<A> io, Function<A,IO<B>> f) {
        return new IO<B>(r -> {
            Tuple<World,A> result = io.transform.apply(r);
            IO<B> ioB = f.apply(result.snd);
            return ioB.transform.apply(result.fst);
        });
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
IO.java:29: error: incompatible types: IO<B>.World cannot be converted to IO<A>.World
            Tuple<World,A> result = io.transform.apply(r);
                                                        ^
  where B,A are type-variables:
    B extends Object declared in method <B>bind(IO<A>,Function<A,IO<B>>)
    A extends Object declared in class IO
```

What I don't understand is the world class has no relationship to the type variable but javac thinks it does. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your goal is with this, but I think you are mistaking the purpose of `World`, and this isn't the best way of thinking about the `IO` monad.  Either way, your definition of `World` implies that "transforms" can add to the input and remove from the output, which is probably undesired behavior.

Comment: The goal is to introduce Haskell to java developers. I think pure IO is Haskell coolest concept so I am just making a simple model of IO. I agree though the stdin list should be readonly.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, but I don't see how something so hairy could be a good way to introduce Haskell's `IO` type. For that, I would suggest an "operational monad" approach, where `IO a` is viewed as a data structure made of primitive commands and continuations.

Comment: Why do you think this is hairy?

Comment: Well, the biggest problem is that it imitates GHC's conceptually broken internal model of I/O. The world isn't really a value you can pass around. An operational monad at least doesn't lie--it leaves the interpretation open.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647852/haskell-actual-io-monad-implementation-in-different-language .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an "operational monad" approach is better for explaining the essence of Haskell I/O. The Haskell version can be quite simple:

```hs
data PrimOp a where
  PutStr :: String -> PrimOp ()
  GetLine :: PrimOp String
  -- Whatever other primitives you want

data MyIO a where
  Pure :: a -> MyIO a
  Bind :: !(MyIO a) -> (a -> MyIO b) -> MyIO b
  LiftPrim :: !(PrimOp a) -> MyIO a

instance Functor MyIO where
  fmap = liftM

instance Applicative MyIO where
  pure = Pure
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad MyIO where
  (>>=) = Bind
```

The `MyIO` values aren't some magical world-passing functions; they're just plain data. We can interpret the data to actually perform the action represented if we so desire:

```hs
runPrimOp :: PrimOp a -> IO a
runPrimOp (PutStr s) = putStr s
runPrimOp GetLine = getLine

runMyIO :: MyIO a -> IO a
runMyIO (Pure a) = pure a
runMyIO (Bind m f) = runMyIO m >>= runMyIO . f
runMyIO (LiftPrim prim) = runPrimOp prim
```

It would actually be possible to write a Haskell compiler whose `IO` type looks a lot like `MyIO`, and whose runtime system interprets values of that type directly.

---

I have attempted a translation to Java below. I've never really been a Java programmer, and it's been a long time since I used it at all, so this may be terribly unidiomatic or even wrong. I imagine you'd probably want to use some version of the "visitor pattern" to represent interpretations of `Bind` and `Pure` (bringing things into the realm of something general like [`Control.Monad.Operational`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational/docs/Control-Monad-Operational.html)), while using a `run` method for a `PrimOp` subclass of `IO`. Since I don't really know the right Java way I've tried to just keep it simple.

```java
public interface IO <A> {
  public A run ();
}

public final class Pure <A> implements IO <A> {
  private final A val;
  Pure (A x) { val = x; }
  public A run () {
      return val;
      }
}
```

The tricky bit is `Bind`, which needs existential quantification. I don't know the idiomatic way to do this in Java, so I did something awkward that seems to work. Namely, I wrote an auxiliary class `OpenBind` that exposes *two* type variables, and then a class `Bind` that wraps up an `OpenBind` leaving one of those variables wild.

```java
import java.util.function.Function;

public final class Bind <A> implements IO <A> {
    private final OpenBind <?,A> ob;

    public <B> Bind (IO <B> m, Function <B,IO <A>> f) {
        ob = new OpenBind <B,A> (m, f);
    }

    public A run() {
        return (ob.run());
    }

    private final static class OpenBind <Fst,Snd> {
        private final IO <Fst> start;
        private final Function <Fst, IO <Snd>> cont;
        public OpenBind (IO <Fst> m, Function <Fst, IO <Snd>> f) {
            start = m;
            cont = f;
        }
        public final Snd run () {
            Fst x = start.run();
            IO <Snd> c = cont.apply(x);
            return (c.run());
        }
    }
}
```

The primops themselves are pretty simple (I couldn't find a Java equivalent of `()` so I wrote my own `Unit`):

```
public class PutStr implements IO <Unit> {
  private String str;
  public PutStr (String s) {
      str = s;
  }
  public Unit run () {
      System.out.print(str);
      return Unit.unit;
  }
}

public final class Unit {
  private Unit () {}
  public static final Unit unit = new Unit ();
}

public class GetLine implements IO <String> {
    private GetLine () {}
    public static final GetLine getLine = new GetLine ();
    public String run () {
      // Replace the next line with whatever you actually use to
      // read a string.
      return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm unclear how to translate the GADTs into java data types but this is a much better solution.

Comment: @KyleMcKean, I've added a translation to Java, with some caveats.

Comment: Some notes from another non-Java guy: There's a duplicate import statement. OpenBind could be a static nested class to limit its visibility. Please provide an example of how this would be used.

Comment: Addendum: [There is a `Void` type in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643906/uses-for-the-java-void-reference-type). I can't help but notice that this reminds me of a list where each element can have a different type (`IO<X>`, where `X ∈ {Unit, String}`).

Comment: @StefanHanke, thanks. I used your static nested class approach. The `Void` type isn't appropriate here because it can't be instantiated. What I want is a value I can actually create (and pass to a function) but that is extremely boring. In Haskell this type is called `()`; in a number of other functional languages it is called `Unit`. Usage is pretty simple: you build an instance of a class implementing `IO`, and then to demonstrate that it represents something meaningful you call its `run` method.

Comment: Are wildcards in java typesafe? Are they the same as existentials?

Comment: @KyleMcKean, they are typesafe, yes. I'm no Java expert and no type system expert, so I can't say if they're exactly the same as existentials, but it appears that a plain `?` (without any super/subclass constraints) means an arbitrary class. Note that we only *use* the fact that `start` and `cont` have matching types inside the `OpenBind` class, which is precisely where we can *see* that they do. If `start` and `cont` were public, and we accessed them from `Bind`, we'd come up with an `IO <?>` and a `Function <?, IO <A>>`, neither of which would be any use without reflection.

Comment: But within `OpenBind`, they have types `IO <Fst>` and `Function <Fst, IO <Snd>>`, which we know perfectly well what to do with.

Answer (score 4):

Leaving aside the fidelity of your approach to replicating Haskell's IO type in Java:

The compiler thinks that the `A` in your `bind` method's signature is the same as the `A` in the class definition.  You've told us it's not in words.  In order to communicate that to the compiler, you need to make things static and introduce a couple of method-level type parameters:

```
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class IO<A> {
    private Function<World,Tuple<World,A>> transform;
    private static class World {
        private ArrayList<String> stdin;
        private ArrayList<String> stdout;
        public World() {
            this.stdin  = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.stdout = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }
    private static class Tuple<F,S> {
        public F fst;
        public S snd;
        public Tuple(F fst, S snd) {
            this.fst = fst;
            this.snd = snd;
        }
    }
    private IO(Function<World,Tuple<World,A>> transform) {
        this.transform = transform;
    }
    public static <A> IO<A> pure(A a) {
        return new IO<A>(r -> new Tuple<World,A>(r,a));
    }
    public static <A,B> IO<B> bind(IO<A> io, Function<A,IO<B>> f) {
        return new IO<B>(r -> {
            Tuple<World,A> result = io.transform.apply(r);
            IO<B> ioB = f.apply(result.snd);
            return ioB.transform.apply(result.fst);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I tried that but I didnt make the methods static, Thanks!

Comment: It would be fine, and arguably nicer, to leave `bind` as a non-static method and just remove the first argument and replace it with `this`.

Comment: @DerekElkins you're probably right, but for now I've just added a disclaimer.  I think there are more issues than just that ...